# attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libngsmshd12.so failed

Tags: database, oracle12c, ubuntu-18.04

I see it is obvious it was not present in my system to copy it in lib folder. Hence requesting any way to overcome this error. Here is output of

```
ld -libngsmshd12 --verbose


attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libngsmshd12.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libngsmshd12.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libngsmshd12.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libngsmshd12.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libngsmshd12.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libngsmshd12.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64/libngsmshd12.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64/libngsmshd12.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libngsmshd12.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib64/libngsmshd12.a failed
attempt to open //lib64/libngsmshd12.so failed 
attempt to open //lib64/libngsmshd12.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libngsmshd12.so failed 
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libngsmshd12.a failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libngsmshd12.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/libngsmshd12.a failed
attempt to open //lib/libngsmshd12.so failed
attempt to open //lib/libngsmshd12.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libngsmshd12.so failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/libngsmshd12.a failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libngsmshd12.so failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64/libngsmshd12.a failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libngsmshd12.so failed
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/libngsmshd12.a failed
ld: cannot find -lngsmshd12
```

I got pop error too (Error in invoking target all_no_orcl in ins_rdbms.mk file) while installing Oracle 12c on my Ubuntu 18.04 version, but skipped thinking ok with losing some functionalities. After installing I got TNS lost contact error which again is due to of this library -lngsmshd12 i believe. Just to know, I updated and copied all .mk files with necessary changes to be done to install Oracle12c. (like -Wl,--no-as-needed, etc)

Here is similar link I checked:

[usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<nameOfTheLibrary>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary)

I have tried re linking too as my oracle binary was 0 bytes, with the help of below link and got no error.
http://ruleoftech.com/2016/problems-with-installing-oracle-db-12c-ee-ora-12547-tns-lost-contact

But while running

```
make -f ins_rdbms.mk install
```

Here is the tail part of error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lngsmshd12
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error for a different library, I too found that linker is looking at the locations with extra `/` in the path i:e

`attempt to open //lib/liblibcppkafka.so failed`

did you find why this is happening ?

Comment: Ok it seems it's not a problem 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879050/ld-searching-malformed-directory-paths